# Writing objects to a file and then reading it back for use

Tags: php, file, object

I was wondering if there was a way to write an array of objects to a file and then read it back for use. I tried to write a `json_encode` array of objects to the file and it is successfully writing to the file, but when attempting to read back and `json_decode` the objects to reuse them, it is failing due to malformed objects - I believe `json_encode` is intended for arrays, and I was not able to find any other working alternative.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `serialize()` function on your array of objects and write into a file, 
then read them back with `unserialize()` function.

Answer (score -1):

jsondecode:

```
<?php  

    $array = array("Name"=>"Vineet","Profile"=>"Developer","Mobile"=>"9015501897");  

    echo json_encode($array);        
?>
```

output is :

```
{"Name":"Vineet","Profile":"Developer","Mobile":"9015501897"}
```

This is the link for the above problem --http://www.phptpoint.com/php-json-example/ 
thanks hope this will be helpfull.